# Simple question about the definition of change of basis matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Definition**

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. Let $B=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_n\}$ and $B'=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ be bases for $V$. We can form the change of basis matrix $P$ by making the $i$th column of $P$ be $[v_j]_B$ for $j=1,...,n$.

My question is does the matrix have this property: Suppose we have $u\in U$ then is it $$[u]_B=P[u]_{B'}$$ or is it the other way around $$[u]_{B'}=P[u]_B$$ I know if $P$ is invertible (which it will be) then we can calculate $P^{-1}$ and use that to move in the opposite direction should we wish but I don't understand which direction we are moving in when we say something like $P$ is the change of basis matrix from $B$ to $B'$ because my thoughts would say this is the matrix with the property $$[u]_{B'}=P[u]_B$$ but my notes have it as the other one.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** In typing up my question I have in fact managed to answer it for myself. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think I may have resolved my issue now. The comment I was reading was actually about a matrix of a map of the identity map not a change of basis matrix. Would I be correct in saying the change of basis matrix from $B$ to $B'$ is the second of the two equalities listed above?

Comment: Actually it's the first one.

Answer (score 1):

It's
$$[u]_B=P[u]_{B'}.$$

To see this, it is enough to check equality on a basis of $V$; we will do it with $B'$. If you take $u=v_j$ in the equation, then
$$[u]_{B'}=[v_j]_{B'}=e_j,$$
where $e_j=(0,\dots,1,\dots,0)$ with the $1$ in the $j^{th}$ position. Then $P[v_j]_{B'}=Pe_j$ is actually the $j^{th}$ column of $P$, which is by definition $[v_j]_{B}$.